# C# make button visible after two criteria are true with bindable property

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I set a button by default to `IsEnabled = false`. After the two `Entries` have an input and are validated, the button should change to `IsEnabled = true`.

This is what I have so far on my MainPage:

```
var button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Text",
                .
                .
                .
                IsEnabled = false
            };

var entry1 = new Entry
            {
                .
                .
                .
            };

var entry1 = new Entry
            {
                .
                .
                .
            };

button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "EnableButtonComand");
```

On my ViewModel I have this:

```
bool isValidatedEntry1 = false;
bool isValidatedEntry2 = false;
bool isAllValidated = false;

public Command EnableButtonCommand { get; }



public bool IsValidatedEntry1
{
    get { return isValidatedEntry1; }
    set { isValidatedEntry1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsValidatedEntry1"); OnPropertyChanged("IsAllValidated"); }
}
public bool IsValidatedEntry2
{
    get { return isValidatedEntry2; }
    set { isValidatedEntry2= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsValidatedEntry2"); OnPropertyChanged("IsAllValidated"); }
}
public bool IsAllValidated
{
    get { return isAllValidated; }
    set { if (IsValidatedEntry1 && IsValidatedEntry2)
            {
                isAllValidated = true;
            } 
            else
            {
                isAllValidated = false;
            }
        OnPropertyChanged("IsAllValidated");
        EnableButtonCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        }
}
```

This in the constructor for my ViewModel Class:

```
public Constructor()
        {
            EnableButtonCommand = new Command(EnableButton, () => !IsAllValidated);
        }
```

My `Validation-Class` is setting the attributes to `True` after validation succeeds.

I worked with breakpoints and it looks like the `IsAllValidated` property is never updated--Only the 'Entry' properties are. Why is this happening, and what should I change?

Comment: What... why are you creating UI in code?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the topic...

Comment: I didn't say it did. It's indicative of deeper issues.

Answer (score 0):

`IsAllValidated` doesn't make much sense as a settable property, as it takes no `value`, and shouldn't need to store anything (since its state is wholly dependent on others', if I'm interpreting your requirements correctly). Instead, I would try something like this:

```
public bool IsAllValidated => IsValidatedEntry1 && IsValidatedEntry2;
```

Comment: I would try adding `EnableButtonCommand.ChangeCanExecute()` to the setters for the two Entry properties (or adding a common method they can call to do that). Alternatively, you may want to check whether `Button.CommandProperty` is the correct binding for the `button.SetBinding` call... None of that tells the button to alter its `IsEnabled` from the initial value of false.

Comment: It seems so. Thanks for your advice but it doesn't work. Have you any other ideas to accomplish my task? It can't be that hard...I am sure I am missing just some little code!